# JS Regex allow single language input

Tags: javascript, regex

I need javascript regex that will allow english or hebrew characters but not both mixed.
for example:

- myuser - OK.
- myאבג - NOT OK.
- אבגדה - OK.

Comment: What about numeric characters?  Can those be mixed with the hebrew?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matches strings entirely of the Hebrew unicode range, or entirely alpha/numeric/underscore.

```
/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+|[\w]+)$/i
```

Got the Hebrew unicode ranges from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet#Unicode_and_HTML).

```
var RE_SINGLE_LANG = /^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+|[\w]+)$/i;
if (!RE_SINGLE_LANG.exec(myText)) {
   alert("NOT VALID");
}
```

Comment: Does javascript regex even handle unicode ranges? And what's with the double escapes?

Comment: agent-j: your solution is almost working perfectly. the code is:
 var RE_SINGLE_LANG = /^(?:[\\u0590-\\u05FF\\uFB1D-\\uFB40]+|[\w]+)$/i;
   if (!RE_SINGLE_LANG.exec(myText)) {
                alert("NOT VALID");
   }

 english only - OK.
 mixed eng and heb - OK.
 hebrew only - NOT OK (i get the alert).

Comment: @tone, The problem was in the `\\`.  In my first solution, I escaped them too much for the /regex/ format.  Please try my new solution.

Comment: If  `/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+|[\w]+)$/i` is not matching your characters, they must be in a different range.  Can you give an example Hebrew string?